# Prove that $f$ is continuous at $x$ IFF $x\not \in D_f = \bigcup _{n\in \mathbb{N}} D_f (1/n)$.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, proof-writing

Given a function $f\colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, let $D_f (\alpha)$ be the set of points $x$ at which $f$ fails to be $\alpha$-continuous.

Q: Prove that $f$ is continuous at $x$ IFF $x\not \in D_f = \bigcup _{n\in \mathbb{N}} D_f (1/n)$.

Definition of $\alpha$-continuous: Let $f$ be defined on $\mathbb R$, and let $ \alpha > 0$. The function $f$ is $\alpha$-continuous at $x \in R$ if there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that for all $y,z \in (x - \delta , x+ \delta)$ it follows that $|f(y) - f(z)| < \alpha $.

I was able to show that for all $\alpha>0$, the set $D_f (\alpha)$ is closed, but I am struggling to begin on this one. Intuitively it makes sense, just failing to explain it rigorously. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$. If $f$ is continuous at $x$, there exists $\delta >0$ such that $\forall y \in \mathbb{R}:$
$$|x-y|<\delta \implies |f(x)-f(y)|<\dfrac{1}{2n}.$$
Then $\forall y,z \in (x-\delta,x+\delta)$, by the triangle inequality we have
$$|f(y)-f(z)|\leq |f(y)-f(x)|+|f(x)-f(z)|<\dfrac{1}{n}$$
Thus, $f$ is $\dfrac{1}{n}$ continuous for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, therefore, $x \not \in D_f(\frac{1}{n})$ for all $n$ and hence we conclude that
$$x \not \in D_f=\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}D_f(\frac{1}{n}).$$

Let $\epsilon>0$ be given. If $x \not \in D_f \iff x \in (D_f)^{c}=\left(\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}D_f(\frac{1}{n})\right)^{c}=\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\left(D_f(\frac{1}{n})\right)^{c}$, then $x \not \in D_f(\frac{1}{n})$  and thus, $f$ is $\frac{1}{n}$ continuous for all $n$.

Now choose $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{N}<\epsilon$. Then $\exists \delta>0$ such that $\forall y,z \in (x-\delta,x+\delta)$,
$$|f(y)-f(z)|<\dfrac{1}{N}<\epsilon.$$
Pick $y=x$ and we have that
$$|x-z|<\delta \implies |f(x)-f(z)|<\epsilon$$
Thus, $f$ is continuous at $x$.